# How to get this linq query to access info from the previous row

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq and I'm trying to figure out how to change this linq query so that where it says prevPrice I'm accessing the Price from the previous row

```
var items = Data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate)
                .Take(days + 1)
                .Average(i => (i.Price - i.prevPrice) * i.Volume);
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume each price has a different date? (down to the second)

Comment: @Juan yes that is correct

Comment: There's 6/12 different ways to get this done...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` function to collect all calculations and than get an average from it

```
var results = new List<int>();
data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate).Take(days)
    .Aggregate((a, b) =>
    {
        results.Add((b.price - a.price)*a.Volume);
        return b;
    });
var result = results.Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

A little different approach. Linq is pretty much a simpler `foreach` so you can use self-incrementing notation to get the element before or after.

```
int i = Data.Count();
int total = Data.Count();

Data = Data.OrderBy(o => o.Date);

var items = Data
    .Where(o => o.Date <= startingDate)
    .Take(days + 1)
    .Average(o => (o.Price - (i == total ? (0 * (i--)) : Data.ElementAt(total - (i--)).Price)) * o.Volume);
```

Comment: This method assumes the data is in a particular order.

Comment: @Juan Question doesn't state specifically to order as you do in your answer but I see what you're getting at. Previous date's record rather than just previous record. I would think doing an order on the whole set before this operation *might* be more efficient instead of ordering the list for each item as you do in your answer. I added a line to take that into consideration. Let me know if that satisfies your point.

Comment: If you take another read, you will see that the intent is to get an average deviation in volume price. Previous price then refers to the price the day before.

Comment: @Juan honestly didn't look at what the math was doing. Makes sense. My update should still account for it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. I whipped it up real quick so check for consistency. I will edit when I have a moment:

```
var items = Data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate)
            .Take(days + 1)
            .Average(i => (
            i.Price - Data.Where(p => p.Date < i.Date)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => o.Price)
            ) * i.Volume);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [MoreLinq's `Pairwise`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#pairwise) function, extra variables can be avoided:

```
var items = Data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate)
            .Take(days + 1)
            .Pairwise( ( previous, current ) => ( current.Price - previous.Price ) * current.Volume )
            .Average();
```

`Pairwise` provides the predecessor and current element as first and second arguments respectively to the `resultSelector` function, except for the first element which is only provided as a predecessor to the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the overloaded `Select()` call, like this:

```
var whatYouNeed = Data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate)
            .Take(days + 1)
            .ToList(); // I'm too lazy to be fancy, so I'm gonna preempt the LINQ here.

var items = whatYouNeed
            .Select((item, index) => 
                new 
                { 
                    Current = item, 
                    Previous = whatYouNeed[(index == 0 ? 0 : index - 1)]
                })
            .Average(item => (item.Current.Price - item.Previous.Price) * i.Volume);
```

**Caveat**: I'm making it so that if the first element is, literally, the first item in the collection, then it will put the first element (again) as `Previous`. If you don't like that, then modify the ternary to do what you want it to do (or leave me a comment for a sample).

Hope this helps!